# How to get the id of telerik element in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

How can i access telerik elements id in my javascript. I tried using 

`$find("<%=radcontrol.ClientID%>")`. 
 But it is not working for me.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code. Also it would help if you could elaborate on what does happen when you tried `$find("<%=radcontrol.ClientID%>")`.

Comment: nothing happen.. that code is not getting executed

Comment: `code is not getting executed` ... this is why you need to flesh out your question ... context is everything

Comment: i mean to say that line of code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try something like this ,

```
var radControl = $telerik.$("[id$='RadEditor1']").attr("id");
radControl = "#" + radControl;// here you 'll get the id telerik of element
$telerik.$(radControl).hide(); //like this you can access it
```

`$=` in a jquery selected means the ID of the element must **end with** the provided string. In this case `"RadEditor1"`